# crontab command fails to create temporary directory

Tags: cron, io, quota

On two of my VMs the `crontab -e` command fails to create a directory in `/tmp` but it works with `mkdir`:

```
/tmp/crontab.oxyaBy: Input/output error
Creation of temporary crontab file failed - aborting
```

strace output:

```
root@vm:~# strace crontab -e
mkdir("/tmp/crontab.1SuJe9", 0700)      = -1 EIO (Input/output error)

root@vm:~# strace mkdir /tmp/crontab.1SuJe9 -m 700
mkdir("/tmp/crontab.1SuJe9", 0700)      = 0
```

Both VMs are running Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (4.4.0-173-generic x86_64)

This is reproducible every time and the problem persists after reboots, fsck says everything is fine and there are no other issues on this VMs. I already tried to reinstall the cron package but nothing changed.

Any ideas? Thank you!

**Edit:** `dmesg` shows

```
EXT4-fs (dm-0): Quota write (off=4080, len=40) cancelled because not block aligned
Quota error (device dm-0): v1_commit_dqblk: dquota write failed
```

The `crontab` command works with `quotaoff` but I still would love to know why `crontab` and `mkdir` behave differently...

Comment: Anything shows up in `dmesg` or is logged in /var/log/messages  or syslog?

Comment: @DevilaN not in syslog or messages, but dmesg shows `Quota write cancelled because not block aligned; Quota error: v1_commit_dqblk: dquota write failed`. At least something to look into, thanks a lot! (But sill no idea why there's a difference between `crontab` and `mkdir`.)

Comment: I don't know how it is handled in ubuntu, but normally `crontab -e` does not create directory, but temporary file in which you are making changes. On my system there is `openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/crontab.Pd430E", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600)` request straced when `crontab -e` is executed. Which package your ubuntu version is using to manage crontabs?

Comment: Version 3.0pl1-128ubuntu2, but all Ubuntu versions seem to handle it this way: `mkdir("/tmp/crontab.Jt0kuD", 0700)` then `open("/tmp/crontab.Jt0kuD/crontab", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600)`.

Comment: There probably is an quota for group `crontab`. When creating directory `cronab -e` probably changes group to `crontab` and is affected by this group quota. But this is wild guess - you should publish full `strace` output or find it out by yourself because I don't have Ubuntu 18 nearby to take a look at this very system.

Comment: It does indeed change the group to crontab. `repquota -g` should show this limit for group crontab, right? This shows File/Block limits soft/hard are all 0. Thank you anyway for your time and knowledge. I think I will simply use the `quotaoff` workaround and accept that there are some things in the world, that I don't understand.

Comment: @DevilaN: In case you want to keep looking, here is the complete strace output: https://pastebin.com/c9f2B2Sc

Answer (score 0):

This is a filesystem issue. And making a directory is different from making a file.

Check the quota settings for the calling user.

In addition, Make sure you can create files there by the same user, and using echo or cat or so, AND you can put something in the file, then trace the issue from that point.

Update: clearly it is a quota related issue as you have updated your question. As a matter of fact, from quota's perspective directories take zero bytes, therefor you can makes as many directories as you want even when quota is reached. But for cron to work, a non zero FILE must be created, which is definitely blocked if max quota has reached.

Comment: Both commands (mkdir and crontab) were executed as root who can create files and folders in /tmp, the only thing that does not work is the crontab command. There are no limits configured for root user or group.

Comment: can we have out for df -i ?

Comment: IUsed: 1521399 (19%), IFree: 6514953

Comment: @Anatol-user3173842: You've said that both commands were executed as root, but `$` sign in prompt is suggesting regular user. Is that an actual situation?

Comment: That $ sign was actually written not copied, I only used root user for all tests.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue because of the quotatool enabled for root user, so I first disabled quotas alltogether using `quotaoff -a` and then repeated the command without issues. Later on, I fixed the quotas, so no more issues there for me...